# React behavior when rendering a component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Let's suppose I have the following `LoadingIndicator` component:

```
export default function LoadingIndicator({ isLoading, children }) {
  return isLoading ? (
    <div>
      <LoadingContainer>
        <Spinner as="span" animation="border" role="status" />
        <br />
        <span>Carregando...</span>
      </LoadingContainer>
    </div>
  ) : (
    { children }
  );
}
```

Now I have the following example of a page that uses this component:

```
export default function DocumentsPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.users.current);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser) dispatch(UsersAction.requestCurrentUser());
  }, [dispatch, currentUser]);

  return (
    <LoadingIndicator isLoading>
      <MyAccountBaseLayout>
        <Wrapper>
          {currentUser.documentsStatus.map((document) => (
            <DocumentCard
              key={document.label}
              label={document.label}
              status={document.status}
            />
          ))}
        </Wrapper>
      </MyAccountBaseLayout>
    </LoadingIndicator>
  );
}
```

The idea is simple: render the loading spinner stuff when isLoading, otherwise render what we received. However, `currentUser` will only be present after the `requestCurrentUser` call, which happens after the first render. Because I iterate over the `currentUser.documentsStatus`, I'm receiving the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentsStatus' of null`.

What I imagined that should happen is that the piece of code that uses the `currentUser` variable should only be rendered when the prop `isLoading` is false, but that's wrong. My question is: with the internal logic of the `LoadingIndicator`, why the error still happen? What is the best approach here?

Comment: `<LoadingIndicator isLoading>` where `isLoading` coming from? it looks like it'll always be true in this case as you haven't assigned a value to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it will always fall into this error since there isn't any initial value for `currentUser.documentsStatus` in your state (probably). You can set an initial state but I guess you don't want to do this. In this case instead of doing the `map` directly there, maybe you can pass this data to another component and do it there.

```
return (
  <LoadingIndicator isLoading={isLoading}>
    <MyAccountBaseLayout>
      <Wrapper>
        <DocumentCards currentUser={currentUser} />
      </Wrapper>
    </MyAccountBaseLayout>
  </LoadingIndicator>
);

function DocumentCards({ currentUser }) {
  return currentUser.documentsStatus.map((document) => (
    <DocumentCard
      key={document.label}
      label={document.label}
      status={document.status}
    />
  ));
}
```

I don't know if this is the strategy you want but without setting an initial state or checking the data before `map` (you don't want to do this probably and use the loading part I guess) you don't have so many options.

By the way, I don't know where do you get `isLoading` but `<LoadingIndicator isLoading>` means `isLoading` will always be true in this component. This is why I use it like `<LoadingIndicator isLoading={isLoading}>` in my example, assuming there is an `isLoading` defined somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, creating the `DocumentCards` component solved the problem. Also, I discovered that I can do things like `currentUser?.documentStatus` using the [Optional Chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining). About the `isLoading`, yeah, I did so just to emphasize when the error was occurring. It looked like a good idea at first haha

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you can check the data existence as I mentioned in my answer but I thought that you didn't want to mix it with this loading strategy. You have this option as well for sure.